# How to dynamically adjust symbology based on user generated table

Tags: leaflet, gis, geojson

I have created a simple leaflet web app that allows for the user to search for the countries that they have traveled.

The user can use a search box or click on the layer on the map. either action will highlight the country green and load the name and flag in an adjacent table.

This works fine. However, problems arise should the user decide to remove a country visited (for example they made a mistake when selecting)

I have included the ability to delete the table items by user click and enabled a function on double click of the layer itself to reset the colour.

What I need is for these two actions to relate to one another. so if the user removes the flag, the related country is reset and vis versa.

I think I need some sort of listener on the click remove or highlight function or perhaps defining the symbology based on the user-generated table of countries visited. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% load static %}
  {% load leaflet_tags %}
  <head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>hello world</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/src/leaflet-search.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/style.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
      #findbox {
        background: #eee;
        border-radius: 0.125em;
        border: 2px solid #1978cf;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 2px 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 26px;
      }
      .search-tooltip {
        width: 200px;
      }
      .leaflet-control-search .search-cancel {
        position: static;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -22px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 50%;
        height: 650px;
      }

      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px; color: #175b81; font-weight: bold;"></p>
    <h3>My World Map</h3>

    <div id="findbox"></div>

    <div id="map" style="height: 680px; width: 48%; display: ;"></div>

    <div class="sidebar" style="display: right;">
      <p style="text-align: centre; font-size: 24px; color: #175b81; font-weight: bold;">My Flags:</p>

      <table style="width: 90%;">
        <tr>
          <td id="name" hidden></td>
          <td id="code" hidden></td>
        </tr>

        <ul id="Countries_Visted"></ul>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      var img1 = "<img src=";
      var im2 = ">";

      var quotes = "'";
      var flagimage_pt1 = "https://www.countryflags.io/";
      var flagimage_pt2 = "/flat/64.png";

      // creating mapbox basemap

      var mapboxAccessToken =
        "pk.eyJ1IjoiY2hyaXNyeWFuLXRlY2giLCJhIjoiY2thY2c3bDZyMDZsNDJ4cHJlZmhwZmFjaCJ9.3GuHRvRz-8fxi4r103z05w";
      var mapbox = L.map("map").setView([46.0, 8.0], 2.2);
      mapbox.doubleClickZoom.disable();

      L.tileLayer(
        "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/chrisryan-tech/ckaxvc0bt10041iqfz5fb7dgj/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=" +
          mapboxAccessToken,
        {
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1,
          attribution:
            '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        }
      ).addTo(mapbox);

      //loading data with style, click function and listener

      var data_layer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'borders_data' %}", {
        style: countriesStyle,
        onEachFeature: countriesOnEachFeature,
      });
      //listener - adding to map on load
      data_layer.on("data:loaded", function (e) {
        layer.addTo(mapbox);
      });

      function countriesStyle(feature) {
        return {
          fillColor: "grey",
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 0.2,
          color: "grey",
          dashArray: 3,
          fillOpacity: 0.2,
        };
      }

      function countriesOnEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          click: function (e) {
            var layer = e.target;
            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 1,
              color: "#fff",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.9,
              fillColor: "green",
            });
            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
              layer.bringToFront();
            }
          },
        });

        layer.on({
          click: load_name_flag,
        });

        layer.on({
          dblclick: clear,
        });
      }

      ///// clearing styling

      var layer = data_layer;
      function clear(e) {
        layer.resetStyle(e.target);
      }

      ///// adding to clicked countries to countries visted list

      function load_name_flag(e) {
        var field1 = document.getElementById("name");
        field1.innerHTML = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        var field2 = document.getElementById("code");
        field2.innerHTML = e.target.feature.properties.iso2;

        var selected_name_search = field1.innerHTML;
        var selected_flag_search = img1 + quotes + flagimage_pt1 + field2.innerHTML + flagimage_pt2 + quotes + im2;
        var selected_features_combine = selected_name_search + selected_flag_search;

        $("#Countries_Visted").append("<li>" + selected_features_combine + "</li>").disabled = true;
      }
    </script>

    <!- search box functionality - searches attribute data -->
    <!-  contained within Geojson from loaded event listener -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/src/leaflet-search.js"></script>

    <script>
      //pointing search function to map layer

      var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        container: "findbox",
        layer: data_layer,
        initial: false,
        collapsed: false,
        propertyName: "name",
        marker: false,
      });

      // search box finds layer and adds country name and flag, changes layer symbol to green

      searchControl.on("search:locationfound", function (e) {
        var field1 = document.getElementById("name");
        field1.innerHTML = e.layer.feature.properties.name;
        var field2 = document.getElementById("code");
        field2.innerHTML = e.layer.feature.properties.iso2;

        var selected_name_search = field1.innerHTML;
        var selected_flag_search = img1 + quotes + flagimage_pt1 + field2.innerHTML + flagimage_pt2 + quotes + im2;
        var selected_features_combine = selected_name_search + selected_flag_search;

        // styles for selected country

        e.layer.setStyle({ fillColor: "green", color: "black", fillOpacity: 0.8 });

        /// adding name and flag to countriesvisted list from searchbox select

        $("#Countries_Visted").append("<li>" + selected_features_combine + "</li>").disabled = true;
      });

      mapbox.addControl(searchControl); //inizialize search control

      // function to remove added layers
      Countries_Visted.onclick = function remove(e) {
        var li = e.target;
        var layer = data_layer;
        var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
        layer.resetStyle(e.target);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a working codepen or codesandbox?  would be a big help to get in there, play around, and help accomplish your goal

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I've not used codepen etc before, but I'll look into it and let you know. I may also host the page so it's possible to see it running.